# java.lang.NullPointerException at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.inject.InjectableValuesProvider.getInjectableValues(InjectableValuesProvider.java:43)

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I am trying to upload file using jersey and postman, I 've found some information from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33237958/rest-jersey-exception-obtaining-parameters) but did not work for me.

**pom file**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Rest class**

```
    import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition;
import com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataParam;

@Path("/uploadTemplate")
@Component("uploadStateAutomationTemplateResource")
public class UploadTemplateResourceImpl implements UploadTemplateResource{
    @Override
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Path("/ftlFile")
    public Response uploadTemplate(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileInputStream,
            @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileMetaData,@FormDataParam("state") String state) {
        :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    }

}
```

UploadTemplateResource interface exact same method signature as mentioned in above class.

**Exception**

```
     Error is thrown from Rest API : com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: Exception obtaining parameters
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.inject.InjectableValuesProvider.getInjectableValues(InjectableValuesProvider.java:51)
        at com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.FormDataMultiPartDispatchProvider$FormDataInjectableValuesProvider.getInjectableValues(FormDataMultiPartDispatchProvider.java:115)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$EntityParamInInvoker.getParams(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:123)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:170)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:67)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:265)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:133)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:83)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:133)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:71)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:996)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:947)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:938)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:399)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:478)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:663)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1597)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:131)
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.inject.InjectableValuesProvider.getInjectableValues(InjectableValuesProvider.java:43)
        ... 50 more
```

**Postman request snapshot**

Please consider contextpath in postman's request URI is valid. 
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Way too late, but worth posting something in case it's useful to others looking for answers.  I got the same error.

This error occurred under Jersey 1.2 when I had a MultivaluedMap parameter in a multipart/form-data end point.  It looks like the Jersey code was trying to work with the parameter when it wasn't relevant and hence the NPE.  In my case removing the parameter from my Web Service (or replacing with a FormDataMultiPart) resolved the problem.

Your case doesn't show that particular scenario, but the same idea obviously applies.  Make sure the client is actually posting to the end point you have shown the code for and is using the multipart encoding.